# How to display image side by side in html

Tags: html, css, oracle-apex

For the below code when previewing I'm able to see images only vertically[see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGxdA.png) but want to show horizontally too(depending on the quantity). below three images are considered as one image and that one completes prints/preview next one horizontally

Can someone help me on this?

```html
htp.p('<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 
}
</style>
');  


FOR x in 1 .. 10 
loop

htp.p(' <div class="column">
<div class="row">
  
<table>
<td>

<tr>
<td>
<img style="text-align: center;" alt="TRENDEST_LOGO"
         src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Ifrqww75cpmhI3mYsk1C28vYmlwwOi_VvuTyrH0xBEKPqed56lwrJINLZJNhFJ1zLSPFDg=s170"
   width="200"  height="50" ></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img style="text-align: center;" alt="TRENDEST_BARCODE"
       src="https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data='||htf.escape_sc(bcode) ||'&code=Code128&translate-esc=true&unit=Fit&hidehrt=True&modulewidth=1" 
       width="200" height="80"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <a title="ITEMS">
    SHIRT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8377;230                          
  </a></td>
</tr>

</td>
</table>
</div>
</div> ');

end loop;
```

Comment: do you really need to put it on table you can attain that using flex or grid inside a div

Comment: when I set all td as one tr all images are displaying horizontally ( see attached ) https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fcf117ee45a8f7d81987cf9ee09e32e620220527083142/376cf7

Comment: Not really to put it on the table just wanted to check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres your sample you can play with. hope this will help and let me know. I use flex then put a gap in it and wrap it.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  grid-gap:10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVrUH3Siiaj4-KM-a4ZhfESeNb9ZmocLBJuXVgVZtEfMQLZYt6jxbEuvloqE-aNvy9OCU&usqp=CAU" >
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVrUH3Siiaj4-KM-a4ZhfESeNb9ZmocLBJuXVgVZtEfMQLZYt6jxbEuvloqE-aNvy9OCU&usqp=CAU" >
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVrUH3Siiaj4-KM-a4ZhfESeNb9ZmocLBJuXVgVZtEfMQLZYt6jxbEuvloqE-aNvy9OCU&usqp=CAU" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a div container and then the elements inside should have `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I'm having two images and one wordings all three should display vertically. And I'm using the loop to preview the same multiple times depending upon the quantity entered and that should be in horizontally(ie) after these images display vertically i want same to be side by side